# Mirroring C# Models in JavaScript - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that uses ajax very heavily (jQuery).  In most cases, the user never leaves the page - just makes various ajax requests to controller actions.

Often, when making an ajax POST, I am passing an object from JavaScript to the controller action.  In most of those cases, that object that I created in JavaScript to pass to the controller also exists as a C# model, so I am really mirroring some of my C# models in JavaScript.

My question is - am I going about this wrong?  My concern is that I will change a property name in my C# model, but forget to change it in JavaScript and will not know about it until it is too late and a user finds it (I realize that unit tests will catch many of these scenarios, but still ...).

I am considering writing some sort of auto-generator to mirror some of my C# classes as JavaScript - but before getting into all of that nonsense I thought I would see if I am missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**

I am using ASP.NET MVC, so when I make an ajax POST to a controller, the data I pass from ajax is automatically parsed into controller method parameters, as long as they have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back and think about it.

All your doing is sending a lump of key/value pairs as data over HTTP.

What you should be doing is mapping those key/value pairs into your domain object / model on the server.

The default mapping can be Model property names but you can't go change the HTTP API when you change the model property names.

This breaks compatibility with anyone using your HTTP API, the contract used to be { foo: .. } and is now { bar: .. }.

Basically your doing it wrong by having Model changes propagate into HTTP API changes.

What you want is a `Model.from(HTTPData)` factory or some other kind of `Model.manipulate(HTTPData)` function.

Comment: I think I get the basic idea you are laying out here - but I am having trouble visualizing an actual implementation.  Let's assume I need to pass 2 values - name & age - from JS to my C# controller via an ajax POST (not necessarily in a <form>).  Let's also assume that I already have a C# Model called NameAgePair that has only these 2 properties.  What would that look like in code (pretty pretty please)?  Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @MattW All my domain objects have a [`.construct`](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/blob/master/src/domain/post.js#L11) method which takes a lump of json data and converts it into the real data object. If I decided to change `content` to `text` in my domain object I would change [this line](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/blob/master/src/domain/post.js#L17) to be `obj.text = post.content`.

Comment: Ok ... so you are saying that you just send the JSON data over to the controller and let the controller decide how to parse it into objects (C# Models)?  In this scenario, if you change the JSON property names in the JS, will your C# Models not get filled correctly?  Thanks again!

Comment: @MattW no What i call the "domain" object, you call the model. In my case `.construct` is a method of the model. And you shouldn't change the json properties because your http interface only accepts a certain json object with certain json properties. If you change the json properties on the client the data should fail the http server-side validation step. Because changing the json you send means sending invalid data. However yes, if you want to change the json format you have to change the client, validation and model construction

Comment: Ok thanks ... that makes sense.  The "domain" object clarification helped me out alot.  Thanks again!

Comment: @MattW also, what we are discussing is what I would call architecture choice. Architecture choices are trade-offs. I personally use one architecture choice because I find it reasonable, however there are a whole other set of valid alternatives with their own advantages / disadvantages. I dont know anywhere near enough about architecture to make any kind of cohesive list. Basically there is no right/wrong way. Everything is a "it depends"

Comment: I slept on it. Part of my problem is that ASP.NET MVC automatically parses the HTTP data from the JavaScript into controller method parameters, so I would not have a need for a '.construct' method. This happens behind the scenes (based on the properties having the same name in JS and C#). That may be a nuance of the technology I didn't make clear in my original post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5662/discussion-between-raynos-and-mattw)

Answer (score 0):

Please use a proper JSON serializer/deserializer.

I used Json.NET for a few clients. http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: Yes, but the data is originating on the client (in JavaScript).  I need to create an object in JavaScript that has similarly named properties to be sent to the controller in JSON format, right?  I may be missing something basic here ...

Comment: @MattW - Yes, but javascript makes this easy.  You just create an object in JSON notation.. ie `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` or whatever your objects are called.  Json is short for JavaScript Object Notation, note the term "object" in there.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Comment: @Mystere Thanks for the input!  I am familar with JSON. The problem is, if my C# Model has a property "a" (like in your example), then I have to mirror that property name in JavaScript. If I were to change the property name "a" in my C# Model, I would need to change the JSON format in my JavaScript to mirror my C# object, otherwise the data won't be automatically parsed by ASP.NET MVC.  What I do today is create JavaScript objects with the same properties as my C# classes, and pass their JSON format to the controller.  However, if property names change, that property is no longer parsed